# Facebook oauth login with Flask

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to use Facebook oauth login in a Flask app via the backend.
Here is the code:

```
import facebook
import json
facebook_config = json.load(open("facebook_client_secret.json", "r"))

@app.route("/login", methods=["GET"])
def login():
    app.secret_key = facebook_config['app_secret']
    fb_app = facebook.GraphAPI(facebook_config['app_id'] + '|' + facebook_config['app_secret'], version='3.0')
    app_id = facebook_config['app_id']
    canvas_url = REDIRECT_URL
    perms = ["email"]
    authorization_url = fb_app.get_auth_url(app_id, canvas_url, perms)
    print("Facebook Authorization URL:", authorization_url)


    return redirect(authorization_url)
```

I set REDIRECT_URL in the Facebook settings. Initially I tried http://localhost/callback but since it did not work, I used https://myhost

It is showing the facebook login; after you enter the credentials, it returns a 500 error
"Sorry, something went wrong."

Note that I took a similar approach with google and that worked.
Any ideas?
I'm open to anything as long as it can be done on the backend instead of frontend javascript.

Comment: Is the 500 coming from Facebook, or from your system after the user got redirected back there?

Comment: It is from Facebook. It never redirects.

Comment: What does the `authorization_url` your system creates look like (**** out the client id, if you want to keep that private.)

Comment: Looks like this: https://www.facebook.com/v3.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=*****&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fintellimosys.com%2Fcallback&scope=email       Note that I defined the hostname intellimosys.com in my hosts file to point to localhost and used that in the Facebook settings.

Comment: Not able to reproduce that. API version 3.0 is very old, but it should update you automatically to the lowest available one.

Comment: I figured it out. I removed "scope" and added state and it started to work. Now I can retrieve user id and name but not email. I still need to know why I cannot retrieve email in a test app. Any thoughts?

Comment: also, I had to update to version 17 of api. Note that the python package does not support it so I had to do it without that package.

Comment: _"I still need to know why I cannot retrieve email in a test app."_ - because you removed the scope, and are therefor not asking for any permissions besides the default, implied `public_profile` any more? Without granted `email` permission, you won't get it.

Comment: so I need to know why when I specify scope, it fails with the error as I described above. Maybe there is a setting that will allow that.